# How to disable certain combination keys (eg. Shift + "certain number key")

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm created a telephone keypad which consists of 0-9 plus hash key (#) and star key (*). I was able to disable other keys except those number keys so that when user type in the textbox provided, it will only allow number keys. Since # is the combination of Shift+3 and * is the combination of Shift+8, my problem is I can't disable other combination key except those two. So, is there any way to handle this problem in order to just allow Shift+3 and Shift+8 only?

```
private void NumDisplayBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard
    if (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9)
        //Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad
        if (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9)
            e.Handled = true;

    if (e.Key == Key.Space) //Disable the space key
        e.Handled = true;

    //Enable the following keys
    if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right)
        e.Handled = false;

    //Determine whether the keystroke is # or *    
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.D3))
        e.Handled = false;
}
```

Comment: if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) && (e.Key == Key.D3 || e.Key == Key.D8))  e.Handled = false;

Comment: Hi @Gusman, as I tried, it still give me the same result.

Comment: if(e.Shift && (e.Key == Key.D3 || e.Key == Key.D8))

Comment: It's still the same, I know the reason why it's still the same even though the statement is correct because I already stated that if e.Key is number key then it displays on the textbox. Since that statement executes first, so whatever statement related to number keys I set at the below of it still can't get what I want. This is my problem and I've no idea how to tackle it.

Comment: @YWah Then change the order of execution. Check for the modifier keys first, then apply the rest of the rules accordingly. Also the [Modifier Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) is a bit field enumeration, so the correct way to determine the exact set of modifier keys pressed is by using bit operations, e.g. `(Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift`. And by the way... in your example, the last conditional, I'm not sure if it's a typo but you checked for `Control` key instead of `Shift` key.

Comment: Hi @IronGeek, thanks for your solution, it works well now. Actually I tried it before but it doesn't work, may be something wrong in my statement. Thanks again..feeling dumb now, lol